# Swift Vapor framework difference in JSON function calls

Tags: json, swift, function, swift3, vapor

My question is what difference in Vapor JSON function calls `return JSON(["foo":"bar"])` vs `return try JSON(node: ["foo":"bar"])`?

Both variants work, what is the right way?

Mixing them like `return JSON(node: ["foo":"bar"])` or `return try JSON(["foo":"bar"])` will make build fail.

```
import Vapor

let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("json") { req in
  return JSON(["foo": "bar"])
}

drop.run()
```

Comment: I can't find the API documentation for Vapor =/ Do you have it handy?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I like their API and ideas behind it but docs are not complete for sure https://vapor.github.io/documentation/guide/json.html

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I tried to check the source code and there is a signature with `node` argument - https://github.com/vapor/json/blob/master/Sources/JSON/JSON.swift#L8 but what is then `JSON` that allows to call it without argument?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, there is API documentation [here](http://api.vapor.codes/), but it is not very complete.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Yeah, that's really quite lacking =/

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, They are always open to PRs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I can answer this one. At first glance, these look pretty similar, but they're very different. The singular reason that everything comes back to in these two initializers is ... GENERICS.

### No External Arg

No external arg initializer refers to `JSON(["foo": "bar"])` above. We use these for **non-failable** initializers for types that can be directly represented in JSON. For example, `[String: JSON]`, `String`, `[JSON]`, `Number(Int, UInt, Double)`, etc..

You may say, "wait a minute, I'm passing `[String: String]` above. Well, here's the thing ... actually we're not. JSON is `ExpressibleAsStringLiteral` so `["foo": "bar"]` above actually becomes `["foo": JSON("bar")]` and allows us to use the no-argument initializer.

### With External Arg `node:`

We use the external argument to help the compiler disambiguate since we were unable to use the same external parameters for failable and non-failable initializers.

If you look through the `node:` initializer, it is a set of generic overloads that allow us to make things easier. As above we mentioned that we can pass `["foo": "bar"]` directly because it converts to `[String: JSON]`. Well, if we have a type that is concretely `[String: String]` and we try to use `JSON(stringDict)` it'll fail. If however we use `try JSON(node: stringDict)` we can use generics to know that `String` is `NodeRepresentible` and we have enough context to properly convert it to JSON. Or at least try to!

By having the `node:` initializer, we can allow multiple different generic variants and work with multiple different types.

### :)

Hope this clears some things up, this is a pretty nuanced area of the code base, happy to elaborate more.